# Numeração de linhas

Tags: mysql

Suponha a seguinte tabela:

```
id -- ano

1 -- 2014

2 -- 2014

3 -- 2014

4 -- 2015

5 -- 2015

6 -- 2016

7 -- 2016

8 -- 2016

9 -- 2016
```

Eu gostaria de obter uma lista com uma contagem/numeração sequencial de linhas agrupadas por ano, conforme segue no exemplo:

```
id -- ano -- count

1 -- 2014 -- 1

2 -- 2014 -- 2

3 -- 2014 -- 3

4 -- 2015 -- 1

5 -- 2015 -- 2

6 -- 2016 -- 1

7 -- 2016 -- 2

8 -- 2016 -- 3

9 -- 2016 -- 4
```

Notem que não se trata de uma contagem simples, onde um count+group by resolveria, mas sim uma numeração de linhas, onde a cada ano o contador volta ao 1.

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Isso dá pra fazer diretamente na linguagem de programação ao invés de fazer na query, é provavel até que fique mais performatico ao ajustar no loop, qual linguagem usa?

Comment: Estou usando c#, mas consegui chegar a uma solução usando variáveis no mySql que vou postar agora.

Comment: C# com o que? asp.net-mvc ou `MySqlDataAdapter.fill()` ou netcore com EntityFrameworkCore? Se puder dar algum detalhe relevante para que seja possivel formular uma sugestão isto irá facilitar.

Answer (score 4):

Dependendo da versão do MySQL que está utilizando, basta usar as *window function* em conjunto com a função `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```sql
SELECT 
  id, 
  ano,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ano) AS posicao
FROM anos
ORDER BY ano, id
```

A saída gerada seria, para o exemplo dado:

```
| id  | ano  | posicao |
| --- | ---- | ------- |
| 1   | 2014 | 1       |
| 2   | 2014 | 2       |
| 3   | 2014 | 3       |
| 4   | 2015 | 1       |
| 5   | 2015 | 2       |
| 6   | 2016 | 1       |
| 7   | 2016 | 2       |
| 8   | 2016 | 3       |
| 9   | 2016 | 4       |
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui chegar a solução usando variáveis. Talvez não seja a solução mais elegante, mas atendeu ao que eu precisava com uma performance muito boa, pois minha lista tem quase 1 milhão de linhas.

```
SET @y = 0;
SET @c = 0;

select id, ano
,if (@y <> ano, @c := 1, @c := @c+1) as numeracao
,@y := ano  -- só nao sei ainda como setar a variavel dentro
            -- do select sem exibi-la no resultado.
from __anos;
```